# The Galois group corresponded to a polynomial of 5 degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I need to show that the Galois extension (the separable and normal) extension of the polynomial $f(x) \in \Bbb Q[x]$: $f(x)=x^5-10x+5$ its Galois group is isomorphic to $S_5$

How to do it when I can't even find it's roots?

Comment: If it's $S_5$, then you won't be able to find its roots

Comment: You can find the roots, actually, just not with radicals alone.  In any event you need to find only the _number_ of real roots (see the answer), which can be pinned down with Descartes' Rule of Signs plus the easily seen sign change in the polynomial between $x=0$ and $x=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It has exactly $3$ real roots](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zqqyyqsper), and [$5$ is prime](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PrimeQ%5B5%5D), so [it follows](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1104807/328173).